# ansible: How to run 'composer install' on production?

Tags: ansible, composer-php, production-environment

First: I am very new to ansible—I just started yesterday.  Most things work quite well (installing packages, cloning my git repo, etc.), but I have not been able to get `composer install` to run to save me.

Here's the setup:

- Laravel 8.x project.
- Dev environment runs under vagrant (Ubuntu 20.04)
- ansible version 2.9.6
- Remote is a Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance.
- Project root is `/var/www/roster`

I have temporarily set the the remote `vendor` directory to `0777` and the owner to `ubuntu` (the EC2 default ssh user) but reset it to `0755` and `root` when done.

I've tried several variations, but when I run the playbook with `ansible-playbook -i ./hosts composer_install.yml`, it just hangs.  Here are the things I've tried:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Composer install
      shell: composer install
      args:
        chdir: /var/www/roster
```

...and:

```
  tasks:    
    - name: Composer install
      composer: command=install working_dir=/var/www/roster optimize_autoloader=no
```

...and (with the ansible-composer plugin installed):

```
  tasks:
    - name: Composer install
      community.general.composer:
        command: install
        working_dir: /var/www/roster
```

I'm sure this is something that can be done, but how?

Comment: "it just hangs" is almost certainly either the process trying to use `sudo` which is prompting for a password, or a similar configuration tool that is asking for input; ansible is buffered, so you wouldn't see the message -- even on failure -- until the task times out. The best outcome is to audit that flow for prompts and fix them (`bash -c "composer install" </dev/null` may help, but ideally you'd already know the things it asks for)

Comment: That could be a possibility, but it’s important to note that composer hates being run as sudo or root.  As in: `Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details`

Comment: I haven't used composer to provide more actionable advice, but just like its npm friend, [composer supports running arbitrary shell](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#command-events) so `{"scripts": {"pre-install-cmd": "sudo rm -rf /*"}}` would (hopefully!) prompt for the sudo password even though composer itself is not run as root. I'm for sure not trying to imply that is happening to you, but rather there are a lot of ways that process could ask for input when no one is there to provide it

Answer (score 8):

Problem is in root user, when you run

```
sudo php /usr/local/bin/composer --working-dir=/path/to/project install
```

Composer ask you

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Continue as root/super user [yes]?
```

Because of that ansible stack on this task.
You must user next construct to fix it

```
- name: "Composer install"
  become: yes
  become_user: not_root_user
  composer:
    command: install
    global_command: false
    working_dir: /path/to/project
```

Comment: Trying this I got error `Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user`

Comment: @EdmundSulzanok then you should probably answer with "yes", so go against composer's recommendation, in order to at least make it pass.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly noted [by Vlad Gor in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65953933/2544163), it is most likely the case that you run the command as `root` (or with `sudo`).

In case you cannot/don't want to switch users, this can be circumvented by using the parameter `--no-interaction` or a little simpler with ansible the corresponding environment variable `COMPOSER_NO_INTERACTION: "1"`

For example:

```yaml
 tasks:    
    - name: Composer install
      composer: 
        command: install 
        working_dir: /var/www/roster
      environment:
        COMPOSER_NO_INTERACTION: "1"
```

Comment: I have spent the whole day looking at how to pass this parameter. In the beginning, I wasn't sure what was the real issue was, but then I have come to the same conclusion and didn't know how to send this parameter. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly allow composer to run as root using environment variables. It's also a good idea to run it in non interactive mode from a script.
This can be useful in a transition period for legacy environments. Just be sure you really want to do this. Maybe it is better to refactor your stack to follow best practices and security standards in the long run.

You can set the environment variables like this:

```
- name: install composer  
  composer:
    command: install
    working_dir: /var/www/roster
  environment:
    COMPOSER_NO_INTERACTION: "1"   
    COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER: "1"
```

Answer (score -2):

Okay, this is not really an "answer" but I was able to successfully run `composer install` via ansible.  The issue in my case was with the latest version composer.  I was on 2.0.4 and, when I rolled back to 1.10.17, all was well.